# Stored Procedure to restore SQL Server database from the backup

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm looking for a procedure which would help to restore my database from the backups. I have googled and couldn't find the extract one which I was looking for. Basically I have 2 kind backups files (some backups with .mdf and .log file and some backups around 30 logical files). Would like to pass 2 argument to the procedure during the execution, backup name and the old and/new database name. Could you please advise me putting up this procedure?

Comment: Why would you want to write a proc to do this? Use SSMS.

Comment: @scsimon Actually there are very good reasons to automate a database restore with a stored procedure.  For instance, a test environment DB that you wanted to restore to a known state every night.

Comment: That's fair @RBarryYoung

Comment: Take a look at [Ola Hallengren's backup/restore stored procedures](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution) which are considered something like a gold standard for backup management for mssql instances.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a stored procedure to restore a database and nothing exists within the product by default. You can certainly write one customized for you specific needs if you like.

Details on RESTORE statement is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql Check it out, try it then come back if you have further questions.

Specific to your ask above, you don't need to specify old DB name if you want to use an existing backup to restore to a new DB name. This is basically a copy operation. The following is a sample of what the script might look like. You should fully understand how the RESTORE statement works (link above) and modify as appropriate for your needs.

```
-- Assuming your original backup was on Pubs database
RESTORE DATABASE Bars
FROM PubsBackups
WITH MOVE 'Pubs_Data' TO 'D:\SQLServer\bars.mdf',
MOVE 'Pubs_Log' TO 'L:\SQLServer\bars.ldf';
```